# How to use CKEditor 5 in Angular 16 with DecoupledEditor

Tags: angular, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to use CKEditor 5 in Angular 16 with a custom editor type. I am getting the error

> "TS2416: Property 'ui' in type 'DecoupledEditor' is not assignable to
> the same property in base type 'DataApi & ElementApi & Editor'

My code is as follows:

```
import  DecoupledEditor  from '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document';

export class TemplateFormComponent implements OnInit {

      Editor = DecoupledEditor;
      ...
      onReady(editor: any) {
         this.editTemp=editor;
         editor.ui.getEditableElement().parentElement.insertBefore(
           editor.ui.view.toolbar.element,
           editor.ui.getEditableElement()
         );
      }
...
}
```

.html:

```
<ckeditor id="txtid" [editor]="Editor" formControlName="text" (ready)="onReady($event)" (change)="changeText($event)" style=" max-width: 650px; border:var(--ck-focus-ring); border-color:#ced4da;"></ckeditor>
```

package.json:

```
...
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-angular": "^7.0.0",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document": "^39.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-core": "^39.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-engine": "^39.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-utils": "^39.0.2",
    "@ckeditor/ckeditor5-watchdog": "^39.0.2",
...
```

I also created a ckeditor.typings.d.ts:

```
declare module '@ckeditor/ckeditor5-build-decoupled-document'{
  const Editor: any;
  export = Editor;
}
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: note that `editor` != `Editor`. I'm not sure if this could be the reason for some problem in your case though.